# Inaccurate results when using C++ standard library for multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I use a C++ library to learn the parameters of a probabilistic model for classification.

The first version of my code was fully sequential and I got good results :

[Results without threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQorM.png)

but the inference time was quite long so I used multi-threading and my code runs well and is faster but the more threads I used, the worst my results get.

[Results with 2 threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVrw8.png)

[Results with 12 threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1bNB.png)

So I guessed it is a data sharing problem between my threads but I don't understand how because to avoid this I copied every data I use into a vector. I split the datafile into n_threads part before passing it to the thread.

```
// --- thread function

void thread_inference(std::vector<std::vector<double>> const &data,
            std::vector<double> const &truth, std::vector<int> const &confusion_vector)
{
    std::vector<int> &confusion_vector_bis = const_cast<std::vector<int> &>(confusion_vector);
    std::vector<double> &truth_bis = const_cast<std::vector<double> &>(truth);
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> &data_bis = const_cast<std::vector<std::vector<double>> &>(data);

    std::vector<double> predictions{};
    predictions = apply_prediction(data_bis);

    compute_confusion_matrix(predictions, testing_truth_bis, confusion_vector_bis);
}

// --- main
for (int i = 0; i < n_threads; i++)
{
    ...
    std::vector<int> confusion_vector{0,0,0,0};
    confusion_vectors.push_back(confusion_vector);

    DataObject data;
    datas.push_back(data);

    DataObject truth;
    truths.push_back(truth);
    ...
}

for (int i = 0; i < n_threads; i++)
{
    threadList.push_back(std::thread(thread_inference, std::ref(datas[i]), 
                std::ref(truths[i]), std::ref(confusion_vectors[i])));
}

std::for_each(threadList.begin(), threadList.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

for (int i = 0; i < nb_threads; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < confusion_vectors[i].size(); j++)
        confusion_vector_final[j] += confusion_vectors[i][j];
```

(I simplified the code to the part I guess is useful)

I used this tutorial (https://thispointer.com//c11-multithreading-part-3-carefully-pass-arguments-to-threads/) to fiure how to pass arguments to my threads.

Comment: `apply_prediction()` and/or `compute_confusion_matrix()` may not be thread-safe; eg they could use global variables. Are you able to confirm whether or not this is the case?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that here, so that people can reproduce what you say. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, please don't use pictures of text. BTW: Start working on the `const_cast` uses, they shouldn't be necessary. Sometimes, just refactoring the seemingly harmless flaws of code fixes real bugs that you just didn't see.

Comment: Needless to say, multithread programming is *much* more than learning how to create  and start threads.  You haven't shown us any synchronization, protection against data races, etc.

Comment: It's impossible to answer without a runnable example. On thing springs to mind. Is just adding up those vectors the right answer? If they're all performing some kind of regression I might expect the best result to be some sort of average not a plain sum. But without more code there's no way to understand what you're doing. In cases where there are multiple solutions combining solutions show hopeless performance.

Comment: Why `const_cast` each argument, just fix signature if you need modification.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, but post text as text,

Comment: adding floating point numbers in different order can yield different results. If you rely on exact same results you need to take some measures to ensure that calculations are done in same order whether sequential or parallel